# Why do I get this error when trying to make a dynamic vector array

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, heap-memory

I want to store elements inside `std::vector<Car>* cars = new std::vector<Car>;` that holds all information name, mileage and year of.

```
struct Car
{
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int milage;
};
```

What I end up with is this error:

```
Error   C2663   'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

What is happening here? As far as I know you would want to store a vector of all the vital information inside the heap then when done you just clear it, right?
What am I doing wrong here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

std::vector<Car>* cars = new std::vector<Car>; // This works
std::vector<Customer>* customers = new std::vector<Customer>;

struct Customer
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Car
{
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int milage;
};

class Main
{
public:
    void start();
    void add_car();
};

void Main::start()
{
    std::cout << "***************************\n";
    std::cout << "CAR RENTING\n\n";
    std::cout << "1. Add Car\n0. Exit\n";
    std::cout << "***************************\n";

    char choice = _getch();

    if (choice == '0')
    {
        return;
    }
    if (choice == '1')
    {
        add_car();
    }
}

void Main::add_car()
{
    std::string xcar;
    unsigned int xyear;
    unsigned int xmileage;

    std::cout << "Enter car name: ";
    getline(std::cin, xcar);
    std::cout << "Enter year of car: ";
    std::cin >> xyear;
    std::cout << "Enter mileage of car: ";
    std::cin >> xmileage;

    Car* car = new Car;
    car->name = xcar;
    car->year = xyear;
    car->milage = xmileage;

    *cars->push_back(*car); // But this does not?

    delete car;
}

int main()
{
    Main* main = new Main;
    main->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cars->push_back(...)`, without a star

Comment: It does not work. Gives me the exact same error.

Comment: As an initial matter, you use the name `Car` before it was defined; in `std::vector<Car>* cars = new std::vector<Car>;` . Show the actual code you are compiling, not a paraphrase. The code you show doesn't produce the error you cite. With this fixed and the star removed, your example [compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/3hcsr6zMP)

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation?

Comment: You are right Igor, it did work now when I changed the vectors beneath all the struct classes and also removed the star. But why did it not work when it was above?

Comment: Why Wouldn't I use dynamic vectors? @ChrisMM

Comment: @NewbCoder because it is not necessary. It is very very rare that you will ever need to use `new` to create instances of standard containers.

Comment: One of the reasons to not use dynamic memory allocation (unless you have to) is neatly shown in your `main()` function, where you have a `new` call without a matching `delete`, and hence the potential for a memory leak. Creating variables on the stack (eg `Main m; m.Start();`) avoids this. Nothing in your code (as it stands) requires dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*cars->push_back(*car);` with :

```
cars->push_back(*car);
```

in your code.
The code then works(compiles) as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/srLhrJl8I).

**Secondly**, move the following two lines:

```
std::vector<Car>* cars = new std::vector<Car>; // This works
std::vector<Customer>* customers = new std::vector<Customer>;
```

after the class `Customer` and `Car` definition.

So the complete code would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include<conio.h>


struct Customer
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Car
{
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int milage;
};
//these next two lines should be here after you have defined Car and Customer
std::vector<Car>* cars = new std::vector<Car>; // This works
std::vector<Customer>* customers = new std::vector<Customer>;
class Main
{
public:
    void start();
    void add_car();
};

void Main::start()
{
    std::cout << "***************************\n";
    std::cout << "CAR RENTING\n\n";
    std::cout << "1. Add Car\n0. Exit\n";
    std::cout << "***************************\n";

    char choice = getch();

    if (choice == '0')
    {
        return;
    }
    if (choice == '1')
    {
        add_car();
    }
}

void Main::add_car()
{
    std::string xcar;
    unsigned int xyear;
    unsigned int xmileage;

    std::cout << "Enter car name: ";
    getline(std::cin, xcar);
    std::cout << "Enter year of car: ";
    std::cin >> xyear;
    std::cout << "Enter mileage of car: ";
    std::cin >> xmileage;

    Car* car = new Car;
    car->name = xcar;
    car->year = xyear;
    car->milage = xmileage;

    cars->push_back(*car); // REMOVED THE *

    delete car;
}

int main()
{
    Main* main = new Main;
    main->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Note in the above code, uou have to define the `vector` after you have defined the classes because those vectors uses those classes.

Comment: It works now but had to change the location of the vectors beneath all the classes to make it work

Comment: @NewbCoder Check out the complete code that i have added at the end of my answer. You have to define the `vector` after you have defined the classes because those vectors uses those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on the various comments above, dynamic memory allocation (using `new`) is unnecessary. The task, as written by the OP, can be accomplished on the stack. Behind the scenes, `std::vector` and `std::string` will almost certainly be using dynamic memory, but that isn't our concern.

*The code as written, once edited as per @Anoop Rana's answer, does work*. However, using dynamic memory when you don't need to has pitfalls: most commonly not releasing allocated memory via `delete` (as shown in the OP's `main()` function).

Since the OP's user name suggests they are new-ish to C++, I hope they will excuse me if I answer with an amended version of the code, which uses the stack, and slightly re-arranges the classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

struct Customer
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Car
{
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int mileage;
};

class CarBooker
{
    std::vector<Car> _vecCars;
    std::vector<Customer> _vecCustomers;
public:
    void start();
    void add_car();
};

void CarBooker::start()
{
    std::cout << "***************************\n";
    std::cout << "CAR RENTING\n\n";
    std::cout << "1. Add Car\n0. Exit\n";
    std::cout << "***************************\n";

    char choice = _getch();

    if (choice == '0')
    {
        return;
    }
    if (choice == '1')
    {
        add_car();
    }
}

void CarBooker::add_car()
{
    std::string xcar;
    int xyear;
    int xmileage;

    std::cout << "Enter car name: ";
    
    std::getline(std::cin, xcar);

    std::cout << "Enter year of car: ";
    std::cin >> xyear;
    std::cout << "Enter mileage of car: ";
    std::cin >> xmileage;

    _vecCars.push_back({xcar,xyear,xmileage});
}

int main()
{
    CarBooker cb;
    cb.start();

    return 0;
}
```

A few points:

- Choose descriptive names for classes, so Main becomes CarBooker
- Avoid global variables, so move the vectors to be members of the CarBooker class
- Create an instance of CarBooker on the stack in `main()`. That will exist for the duration of the programme and be tidied up automatically.
- Again use the stack when adding Cars to the vector, and take advantage of the default Car constructor.